# Expo notification received while in the app causes the expo project to reload

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo, expo-go

I am building an Expo app and I am trying to use expo-push-notifications to make an action once the user is in the app and the notification is sent. The notification sends but when I am in the expo app once the notification is received the whole project starts reloading for a while until it says that there is something wrong with the connection. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

try to upload the project on expo with this command

```
eas build -p android --profile preview
```

It could be the projectId in app.json is invalide, that is why you getting this error